# What way to "rank" dataset Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, formula

Situation is as follows:

I have a database with 40.000 cities. Those cities have certain types of properties with an value.
For example "mountains" or "beaches". If a city has lots of mountains the value for mountain will be high if there are less mountains the number is lower.

**Table with city name and properties and values:**

[image]

With that, I have a table with the avarage values of all those properties.

**What I need to happen:** I want the user search for a city with has one or multiple properties, find the best match and attach a score from 0 - 100 to it.

The way I do this is as follow:

**1.** I first get the 25%, 50% and 70% values for the properties:

```
_var_[property]_25 = [integer]
_var_[property]_50 = [integer]
_var_[property]_70 = [integer]
```

**2.** Then I need to use this algorithm:

```
_var_user_search_for_properties = [mountain,beach]
_var_max_property_percentage = 100 / [properties user search for]

_var_match_percentage = 0

for each _var_user_search_for_properties


     if [property] < _var_[property]_25 then

          _var_match_percentage += _var_max_property_percentage

     elseif [property] < _var_[property]_50 then

          _var_match_percentage += _var_max_property_percentage / 4 * 3

     elseif [property] < _var_[property]_75 then

          _var_match_percentage += _var_max_property_percentage / 4 * 2

     elseif [property] < 0 then

          _var_match_percentage += _var_max_property_percentage / 4 * 1

     end if 

next

order all rows by _var_match_percentage desc
```

**The question is:** is it posible to do this with MySQL? 
How do I calculate this "match percentage" with it?

Or wil it be faster to get all the rows and indexes out of the database and loop them all trough .NET?

Answer (score 0):

If the percentages can be stored in the database, you could try MySQL's LIMIT clause. See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx.

Comment: Thats not possibles. The item the user can search for can be more than 10.000 combinations. Like [mountains and beaches], [mountains alone], [mountains, beaches, vulcanos], [etc]

Comment: What if you had an aggregated percentage column on a database table. Perhaps this could be populated at run time?

Comment: It is not possible to make an percentage index on forhand. There are too many combinations. I should calculate it at runtime but I need to find out what the fastest way is to do it.

Comment: It was just a suggestion.